# Hibernate - Is including Set and OneToMany annotation in parent Entity necessary?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the below parent entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityA", catalog = "mycatalog")
public class EntityA implements java.io.Serializable {

private int parentId;
private String a;
    private Set<EntityB> entityBs = new HashSet<entityB>(0);

public EntityA() {
}

public EntityA(int parentId) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
}

public EntityA(int parentId, String a) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.a = a;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "PARENT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getParentId() {
    return this.parentId;
}

public void setParentId(int parentId) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
}

@Column(name = "columnA", length = 64)
public String getA() {
    return this.a;
}

public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "EntityA")
public Set<EntityB> getEntityBs() {
    return this.entityBs;
}

public void setEntityBs(Set<EntityB> entityBs) {
    this.entityBs = entityBs;
}
```

and the below child entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityB", catalog = "mycatalog")
public class EntityB implements java.io.Serializable {

private int childId;
private EntityA entityA;
private String b;


public EntityB() {
}

public EntityB(int childId, EntityA entityA) {
    this.eventId = eventId;
    this.entityA = entityA;
}

public EntityB(int childId, EntityA entityA, String b) {
    this.childId = childId;
    this.entityA = entityA;
    this.b = b;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "CHILD_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getChildId() {
    return this.childId;
}

public void setChildId(int childId) {
    this.childId = childId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false)
public EntityA getEntityA() {
    return this.entityA;
}

public void setEntityA(EntityA entityA) {
    this.entityA = entityA;
}

@Column(name = "columnB", length = 64)
public String getB() {
    return this.b;
}

public void setB(String b) {
    this.b = b;
}
}
```

I have noticed that querying those entities work even if I do not include the Set and the OneToMany annotation in the parent table. See below parent without the Set:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityA", catalog = "mycatalog")
public class EntityA implements java.io.Serializable {

private int parentId;
private String a;


public EntityA() {
}

public EntityA(int parentId) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
}

public EntityA(int parentId, String a) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.a = a;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "PARENT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getParentId() {
    return this.parentId;
}

public void setParentId(int parentId) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
}

@Column(name = "columnA", length = 64)
public String getA() {
    return this.a;
}

public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
}

}
```

Can you please explain the difference and if and when it is necessary to include the Set in the parent table?

Comment: Tell me one thing when you don't add `Set` and `OneToMany` in parent then what will be relation of `EntityA` and `EntityB`.To map one `EntityA` having multiple entries of `EntityB` you will need set in `EntityA` other wise object of `EntityA` with `ManyToOne` in `EntityB`

Comment: Yes,Keeping OneToMany in parent or ManyToOne in child does not affect the DB,it will create parents ID as foreign key in child.Only the difference is `EntityA` can hold multiple objects(`set`) of child.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parent entity has a one-to-many relationship to it's children.

The relationship is is mapped by a join column, and this column is always in the table of the many-side, which is therefore called the **owning** side. So technically, the relationship is a unidirectional one, from the children to their parent.

The table for the parent entity does not contain any relationship information and it is therefore called the **non-owning** or **inverse** side. JPA implementations can 'emulate' a bidirectional relationship if a properly annotated `children` field is added on the parent side, but it is not necessary.

If you need to traverse from a parent to it's children, you can add the field. If you only traverse from the children to the parent, do not add it.

You can notice that the non-owning side must tell the persistence provider the attribute name, by which it is referenced on the owning side, using the `mappedBy` attribute, so the relationship can work bidirectionally on the object level.